# How to create a logic to cycle the contents within the HTML with php

Tags: php, html

I have a following html code and it's meant for showing 6 ads.
What I want to do is to create a logic to loop cycle the following contents  with php.
For example: Currently the Ads1&2 are at the  first and the second place from the top, but when a certain method gets 
called the Ads1 & 2 will go down Ads5&6 and the Ads3&4 will be taking the first and the second position(cycling).
My explanation might be confusing but what I want to do is to loop two  tags whenever a method gets called(like a revolver gun). 
Actually I want to cycle the contents every 2 weeks with the following code. And should I use a Session to keep the data? How can I manage to do this ? I would love to hear from you.

```
$weekInYearNumber = (int)date('W');
$weekDayNumber = (int)date('w'); 
if ($weekInYearNumber % 2 == 0) {

}

<div class="ContentsWrap">
                <ul class="List_1">
                    <li>
                        <a>Ads1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>Ads2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="List_2">
                    <li>
                        <a>Ads3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>Ads4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>Ads5</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>Ads6</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will not work as it is:

```
$weekInYearNumber = (int)date('W');
$weekDayNumber = (int)date('w'); 
if ($weekInYearNumber % 2 == 0) {
   // Rotate here
}
```

First, if you only run the rotating every second week, you'd have to save the status so it is kept for two weeks.
Second, this code will be run every time your page is accessed. That means, you'd also have to save the information `I have already rotated this week`.
You can do this, of course, but you can do it without saving (to a database), too.
To do that, use the code below instead of yours. Explanation in comments:

```
// Fetch your ads and put them into an array (this is not yet rotated):
$ads = ['ad1', 'ad2', 'ad3', 'ad4', 'ad5', 'ad6'];

// We calculate the number of weeks since 1970-01-01 
// to always have the same basis for our calculation. 
// If you use (int)date('W') you will have a change each new year.
$weeknumber = floor(time() / 86400 / 7);

// Every two weeks, we rotate 2 items, which makes (count of ads) weeks for a full rotation.
$rotate = $weeknumber % count($ads);

//But we only rotate every two weeks
$rotate = floor($rotate / 2);

//Now, we rotate!
for ($i = 0; $i < $rotate; $i++) {
    // Push two elements to the end of the array
    array_push($ads, array_shift($ads));
    array_push($ads, array_shift($ads));
}

// Output your ads as you like and you are done.
```

Comment: What should I do if I have want to rotate 8 contents ? should I replace  6 with 8 ?

Comment: I updated the code to work with a variable count of ads. They still need to be a multiple of two, however.

Comment: Should I use the Session to save the values ? And which values should I save ? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You mean my remarks at the top of the answer? No, the session would not work. You need a persistent storage for that, like a database. Or you use my solution.

Comment: Does it mean that your sample code is enough for my solution ?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'lll rephrase the answer to make that obvious.

Comment: Are you sure the following is correct? Because the $rotate looks like it's overwritten. And how can I check if your sample 
 code is actually working properly?
 
`// Every two weeks, we rotate 2 items, which makes (count of ads) weeks for a full rotation.
$rotate = $weeknumber % count($ads);

//But we only rotate every two weeks
$rotate = floor($weeknumber / 2);`

Comment: You're right, that was an error. I fixed it. You can test it by incrementing the rotation frequency: `$weeknumber = floor(time() / 60);` should rotate not every two weeks but every two minutes.